# LiquiBase CLI BASH script not outputting full CLI with ECHO

Tags: bash, jenkins-pipeline, liquibase

Hey all I am new to the world of BASHing :)

I am trying to put together this CLI line of code by doing the following:

```
echo "------"
echo '--url=$URL '\
    '--username=$UN '\ 
    '--password=$PW '\
    '--referenceUrl=$RURL '\
    '--referenceUsername=$RUN '\
    '--referencePassword=$RPW '\
    '--changeSetAuthor=TD '\
    '--diffTypes=tables, views, columns, indexes, foreignkeys, primarykeys, uniqueconstraints '\
    '$LIQUI_ACTION'
echo "------"
```

And the output I am getting is this:

```
------ 
--url=$URL  --username=$UN  
/jenkins/liquibase-3.6.2/liquibase: line 141: --password=$PW : command not found
```

I can tell right off that its not placing the varibles' value within the cli. Second, I'm not sure why its saying **command not found** when I am only outputting text? I am just doing the above to make sure all of it is indeed the correct data in the $ and also that it's spaced between each command correctly.

So any help about the above would be great!

**UPDATE FOR @RavinderSingh13:**

[image]

code used:

```
echo "------"
echo "--url=$URL \
--username=$UN \ 
--password=$PW \
--referenceUrl=$RURL \
--referenceUsername=$RUN \
--referencePassword=$RPW \
--changeSetAuthor=TD \
--diffTypes=tables, views, columns, indexes, foreignkeys, primarykeys, uniqueconstraints \
$LIQUI_ACTION"
echo "------"
```

Comment: Could you please try changing your 2nd echo's first line to  `echo "'--url=...` AND 2nd echo's last line TO `'$LIQUI_ACTION'"`, it worked for me when I did these changes.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 that seems to have worked but there is a lot of spacing between each command. **see my update to the OP**

Comment: Could you please do let me know if you want to print `$var` values too? Or literally you want to print echo's output as it is in new lines without variables values.

Comment: I would need them all on one line sence its doing a **java -cp "$CP" $JAVA_OPTS 'liquibase.integration.commandline.Main [liquibase cli goes here]**

Comment: sure, for output will it be like `'--url=$URL ' '--username=$UN '` and so on.. or `'` is not needed. Could you please post sample of expected output, trying my best here to help, cheers.

Comment: --output1=this --output2=soemthing --output3=anotherthing.......

Comment: so all together would look something like this: **java -cp "$CP" $JAVA_OPTS 'liquibase.integration.commandline.Main --output1=this --output2=soemthing --output3=anotherthing...etc**